# Google Maps V3: How to disable "street view"?

Tags: google-maps

There is a "person" icon which allows user to view "Street View". I don't want this functionality on my map, is there a way to remove it or disable it?

[Street View](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview.html)

Answer (score 289, accepted):

The answer is actually in the 2nd paragraph you linked to, but your code should look something like this:

```
 var mapOptions = {
      center: mapCenter,
      zoom: 10,
      streetViewControl: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };
```

Comment: just noticed that disabling this control "after the fact" when the it's already been added to the map via `map.setOptions({streetViewControl: false});` removes the pegman control box in the upper left, but still ends up leaving the pegman on the map.

Comment: If you want to HIDE the Street View control you need to place `streetViewControl` option before `mapTypeId`. Otherwise, you end up with the Street View control showing disabled.

Comment: This URL contains all the properties you can modify here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#Adding_Controls_to_the_Map

Answer (score 11):

I'd like to add to the chosen answer and say that if you want to remove the zoom controls (plus-minus buttons) too, then change

```
  streetViewControl: false,
```

with

```
   disableDefaultUI: true,
```

It was more useful for a mobile touchscreen, since you can zoom in with two fingers.

Comment: streetViewControl: false -> It removes only street view and it works but for removing the zoom controls (plus-minus buttons) too, you answer not work by replacing      streetViewControl: false,
with

   disableDefaultUI: true,

Comment: `disableDefaultUI: true` is not necessary in order to remove only the street view button.

Comment: Yes it disables the whole ui aka streetview button+ zoom buttons etc. I'm using it on my app and it still works. I added this comment to give an extra info because when i searched for disabling the whole interface this page came up first.

Comment: in React Google Maps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54786236/2223106 add `streetViewControl: false` to the `options` param of the `<GoogleMap` component.