# Google Maps API v3 panning & compass control failure

Tags: google-maps-api-3, panning

This map renders with a strange shred of white in place of the panning/compass control (top left). It disappears on mouse over and returns on mouse out.

A screen shot is available here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/52037.jpg

Any thoughts on why this is happening? Grateful always for your guidance.

A.C.

( In context, http://www.whiskyfair.com.au/209/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's the street view control. 
Just put `streetViewControl: false` in your config of the map.
See [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls) for more

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't seem to have worked... I'm fairly sure it's supposed to be the panning control, as there is a vague, round silhouette that is perhaps a semi-transparent gradient overlay for it?

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: You were right - it was the peg man. As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776953/google-maps-v3-how-to-disable-street-view , I just added `map.setOptions({streetViewControl: false});` to remove the icon post hoc.

Apparently it doesn't disappear completely if you don't do this...?

Thanks again, alkis

Comment: Can't seem to make my map run in jsfiddle, but if it interests you, you can find my best effort at http://jsfiddle.net/9JZww/12/