# How to disable street view with react-google-maps?

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

I'm using the [react-google-maps](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps) package to render a Google Map in my react application. I would like to disable street view.

From [the documentation](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#googlemap), I see there are props for:

- defaultStreetView
- streetView

### I have tried using both with false - but neither works. Does anyone know how to disable street view functionality via this package?

Code snippet here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from "react-google-maps";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Map = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap((props) => {
    return(
        <GoogleMap 
            defaultZoom={17}
            defaultCenter={{ lat: props.lat, lng: props.lng }}
            // defaultStreetView={false}
            // streetView={false}
        >
            {props.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={{ lat: props.lat, lng: props.lng }} />}
        </GoogleMap>
    )
}))

Map.propTypes = {
    lat: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    lng: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    isMarkerShown: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}

export default Map;
```

Answer (score 18):

It seems the props defaultStreetView and streetView were actually not relevant in this case.

### The way to implement this is to pass { streetViewControl: false } to the options prop.

Correct code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from "react-google-maps";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Map = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap((props) => {
    return(
        <GoogleMap 
            defaultZoom={17}
            defaultCenter={{ lat: props.lat, lng: props.lng }}
            options={{streetViewControl: false}}
        >
            {props.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={{ lat: props.lat, lng: props.lng }} />}
        </GoogleMap>
    )
}))

Map.propTypes = {
    lat: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    lng: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    isMarkerShown: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}

export default Map;
```